# Why does my local storage function does not update variable?

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to create an incremental game or clicker game or idle game. And everything else is fine, but when it comes to the save and load function it's broken. So my load function works wonderfully, but the problem is that my save function won't save the updated variable, instead, it saves the not updated variable which basically makes the saving and loading pointless.

Code:

```
function saving() {
    localStorage.setItem('save',JSON.stringify(save));
    alert("save correctly!");
}

function load() {
    var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    if (typeof savegame.Cookies !== "undefined") cookies = savegame.Cookies;
    if (typeof savegame.Cursors !== "undefined") cursors = savegame.Cursors;
    if (typeof savegame.Farms !== "undefined") farms = savegame.Farms;
    console.log("cookies : ", cookies);
    console.log('farms :', farms);
    console.log('cursors :', cursors);
}
```

and I defined the variable "save" as the following.

```
var save = {
    Cookies: cookies,
    Cursors: cursors,
    Farms: farms
}
```

and the cookies, cursors, and farms, variables are all set to zero.
After I increment the value in my game, however, the save variable is still using the not incremented variable.
I want it to save the variable like this: 2000 cookies, 30 cursors, 7 farms, instead of all 0.
I am fairly new to js and I've been trying this for the last two days now.

Maybe it's just some ignorant and careless mistake, someone please point it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `saving` method on every change of the variable `save`.

Comment: Can you explain it better? I do not understand exactly how to do that.

Comment: Your app in different moments will change variable save. Whenever some part of the code change this variable, you have to call saving(save) in order to update localstorage.

Comment: it would be lovely if you can list an example, so do I just do saving(save) inside a code where it changes the variable?  Like when my "cookies" variable changes I have to add saving(save) right under the code that caused the increment?